# Conditional enabled / disable asp.net mvc textbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, textbox, disabled-input

This is what I tried:

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EntryDate, new { style="width:90px;",((_new || _modify) ? @disabled="disabled":"") }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EntryDate)
```

Comment: Cant you just use @if(comeCondition) { @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EntryDate) } else { @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EntryDate, new { @disabled = "disabled") }

Comment: Well I was hoping there is a simple and elegant way to to it

Comment: OK, will post answer

Answer (score 2):

The following will work because there is only one html attribute

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EntryDate, (_new || _modify) 
  ? new { @disabled = "disabled" } 
  : null)
```

However once you add the style attribute, this will generate an error because there is no implicit conversion between `new { @disabled = "disabled", @Style="width:90px;" }` and `new { @Style="width:90px;" }` so you need to do this in an `if` block

```
@if(_new || _modify) {
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EntryDate, new { @disabled = "disabled", style="width:90px;")}
} else { 
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EntryDate, new { style="width:90px;" })
}
```

**Edit**

Casting the html dictionary to `object` seems to work but I've not fully tested this (and I'm not sure that its *"a simple and elegant way to to it"*)

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EntryDate, (_new || _modify) 
  ? (object)new { @disabled = "disabled", style="width:90px;" } 
  : (object)new { style="width:90px;" })
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but try this one:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EntryDate, (_new || _modify) ? new{ @Style="width:90px;", @Disabled="disabled"} : new{ @Style="width:90px;"})
```

Comment: Are you sure these anonymous types will be compatible? Did you test it?